# How do I load a tab-delimited file of mixed datatype into numpy or pandas?

Tags: python, numpy, pandas

I have a tab delimited dataset that loads into Excel looking something like this in terms of data types, but has dimension 83 x 23275.  As you can see, this dataset is of mixed type, with the 0th row and column of type string.

```
               "A"         "B"         "C"         "D"
"2000-01-01"  0.469112 -0.282863 -1.509059 -1.135632
"2000-01-02"  1.212112 -0.173215  0.119209 -1.044236
"2000-01-03" -0.861849 -2.104569 -0.494929  1.071804
"2000-01-04"  0.721555 -0.706771 -1.039575  0.271860
"2000-01-05" -0.424972  0.567020  0.276232 -1.087401
"2000-01-06" -0.673690  0.113648 -1.478427  0.524988
"2000-01-07"  0.404705  0.577046 -1.715002 -1.039268
"2000-01-08" -0.370647 -1.157892 -1.344312  0.844885
```

Using pandas or numpy, how can I load this sort of data and access the numbers associated with their proper labels?  I would even be happy with two vectors of labels (83 and 23275 length for row and column) of datatype string, and then a matrix of float64 (82x23274 for the float data).

I got as far as loading the file into numpy and pandas respectively, but haven't been successful at accessing any of my data.

```
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd

#numpy
path = "C:/nature13173-s4.txt"
e18 = np.genfromtxt(path, delimiter = '\t')
print(e18.shape)

#pandas
df=pd.read_csv(path, sep='\t',header=None)
```

Comment: Is that your raw data? That means, if I copy/paste it into a `.txt` file I would be replicating it properly?

Comment: Can you access this link? http://www.nature.com/nature/journal/v509/n7500/extref/ nature13173-s4.txt

Comment: Check the answer by @nader-hisham, this is a typical structure and pandas can handle with no problem (pd.read_csv with default parameters ). I can acces all data in the usual way with pandas.  What can you or cannot access?

Answer (score 3):

I cut-n-pasted your sample to a file. That doesn't carry over tabs well, so I'm using the default 'white space' delimiter.

My first try:

```
e18=np.genfromtxt('stack33662863.txt',names=True)
```

gave me errors

```
ValueError: Some errors were detected !
Line #2 (got 5 columns instead of 4)
```

That's because the 1st line has 4 column headers, but none for the date column.  So I'll have to skip the header line and give my own field names:

```
In [624]: e18=np.genfromtxt('stack33662863.txt',names=['date','A','B','C','D'],skip_header=1)
In [625]: e18
Out[625]: 
array([(nan, 0.469112, -0.282863, -1.509059, -1.135632),
       (nan, 1.212112, -0.173215, 0.119209, -1.044236),
       (nan, -0.861849, -2.104569, -0.494929, 1.071804),
       (nan, 0.721555, -0.706771, -1.039575, 0.27186),
       (nan, -0.424972, 0.56702, 0.276232, -1.087401),
       (nan, -0.67369, 0.113648, -1.478427, 0.524988),
       (nan, 0.404705, 0.577046, -1.715002, -1.039268),
       (nan, -0.370647, -1.157892, -1.344312, 0.844885)], 
      dtype=[('date', '<f8'), ('A', '<f8'), ('B', '<f8'), ('C', '<f8'), ('D', '<f8')])
```

Almost - except 'date' column is `nan`.  Let's use `dtype=None` to tell it to deduce datatype for each column, rather than assume all are float.  An alterantive is to  give a dtype for each column.

```
In [626]: e18=np.genfromtxt('stack33662863.txt',names=['date','A','B','C','D'],skip_header=1,dtype=None)
In [627]: e18
Out[627]: 
array([(b'"2000-01-01"', 0.469112, -0.282863, -1.509059, -1.135632),
       (b'"2000-01-02"', 1.212112, -0.173215, 0.119209, -1.044236),
       (b'"2000-01-03"', -0.861849, -2.104569, -0.494929, 1.071804),
       (b'"2000-01-04"', 0.721555, -0.706771, -1.039575, 0.27186),
       (b'"2000-01-05"', -0.424972, 0.56702, 0.276232, -1.087401),
       (b'"2000-01-06"', -0.67369, 0.113648, -1.478427, 0.524988),
       (b'"2000-01-07"', 0.404705, 0.577046, -1.715002, -1.039268),
       (b'"2000-01-08"', -0.370647, -1.157892, -1.344312, 0.844885)], 
      dtype=[('date', 'S12'), ('A', '<f8'), ('B', '<f8'), ('C', '<f8'), ('D', '<f8')])
```

Looks pretty good. Data is all there.

I can access attributes and values with:

```
In [628]: e18.shape
Out[628]: (8,)
In [629]: e18.dtype
Out[629]: dtype([('date', 'S12'), ('A', '<f8'), ('B', '<f8'), ('C', '<f8'), ('D', '<f8')])
In [630]: e18['date']
Out[630]: 
array([b'"2000-01-01"', b'"2000-01-02"', b'"2000-01-03"', b'"2000-01-04"',
       b'"2000-01-05"', b'"2000-01-06"', b'"2000-01-07"', b'"2000-01-08"'], 
      dtype='|S12')
In [631]: e18['A']
Out[631]: 
array([ 0.469112,  1.212112, -0.861849,  0.721555, -0.424972, -0.67369 ,
        0.404705, -0.370647])
```

---

Another option is to load the data without `names`

```
In [636]: e18=np.genfromtxt('stack33662863.txt',skip_header=1)
In [637]: e18.shape
Out[637]: (8, 5)
In [638]: e18[:3,:]
Out[638]: 
array([[      nan,  0.469112, -0.282863, -1.509059, -1.135632],
       [      nan,  1.212112, -0.173215,  0.119209, -1.044236],
       [      nan, -0.861849, -2.104569, -0.494929,  1.071804]])
```

Now it is all floats, a 2d array, but with nan in the 1st date column.  We can just slice that off, to get a nice 2d array:

```
In [639]: e18[:,1:]
Out[639]: 
array([[ 0.469112, -0.282863, -1.509059, -1.135632],
       [ 1.212112, -0.173215,  0.119209, -1.044236],
       [-0.861849, -2.104569, -0.494929,  1.071804],
       [ 0.721555, -0.706771, -1.039575,  0.27186 ],
       [-0.424972,  0.56702 ,  0.276232, -1.087401],
       [-0.67369 ,  0.113648, -1.478427,  0.524988],
       [ 0.404705,  0.577046, -1.715002, -1.039268],
       [-0.370647, -1.157892, -1.344312,  0.844885]])
```

I could get the same array with `usecols`. With many more columns in the real data this might not be as good (but feel free to try it):

```
e18=np.genfromtxt('stack33662863.txt',skip_header=1,usecols=range(1,5))
```

You could load the dates separately with:

```
In [647]: np.genfromtxt('stack33662863.txt',skip_header=1,usecols=0,dtype=None)
Out[647]: 
array([b'"2000-01-01"', b'"2000-01-02"', b'"2000-01-03"', b'"2000-01-04"',
       b'"2000-01-05"', b'"2000-01-06"', b'"2000-01-07"', b'"2000-01-08"'], 
      dtype='|S12')
```

---

Yet another option - define a `dtype` with all of the numeric columns:

```
In [654]: dt=np.dtype([('date','S12'),('data','float',(4,))])
In [655]: e18=np.genfromtxt('stack33662863.txt',skip_header=1,dtype=dt)
In [656]: e18['date']
Out[656]: 
array([b'"2000-01-01"', b'"2000-01-02"', b'"2000-01-03"', b'"2000-01-04"',
       b'"2000-01-05"', b'"2000-01-06"', b'"2000-01-07"', b'"2000-01-08"'], 
      dtype='|S12')
```

Now you can retrieve the numeric part as 2d array:

```
In [658]: e18['data']
Out[658]: 
array([[ 0.469112, -0.282863, -1.509059, -1.135632],
       [ 1.212112, -0.173215,  0.119209, -1.044236],
       [-0.861849, -2.104569, -0.494929,  1.071804],
       [ 0.721555, -0.706771, -1.039575,  0.27186 ],
       [-0.424972,  0.56702 ,  0.276232, -1.087401],
       [-0.67369 ,  0.113648, -1.478427,  0.524988],
       [ 0.404705,  0.577046, -1.715002, -1.039268],
       [-0.370647, -1.157892, -1.344312,  0.844885]])
```

Answer (score 3):

actually this worked fine with me using pandas , instead use `\s+` as your separator rather than `tab` , it seems to be that `tab` character is not the separator in your case

```
In [10]:
pd.read_csv('C:/nature13173-s4.txt' , sep = '\s+')
Out[10]:
               A           B            C          D
2000-01-01  0.469112    -0.282863   -1.509059   -1.135632
2000-01-02  1.212112    -0.173215   0.119209    -1.044236
2000-01-03  -0.861849   -2.104569   -0.494929   1.071804
2000-01-04  0.721555    -0.706771   -1.039575   0.271860
2000-01-05  -0.424972   0.567020    0.276232    -1.087401
2000-01-06  -0.673690   0.113648    -1.478427   0.524988
2000-01-07  0.404705    0.577046    -1.715002   -1.039268
2000-01-08  -0.370647   -1.157892   -1.344312   0.844885
```